# How to read/import a Sqlite database in Blazor WASM?

Tags: c#, sqlite, blazor, webassembly

Is it even feasible? All I can find is how to get it running from within the app and nothing that approaches the import of the file which will be a `byte[]` file and make it so that it could be possible to instantiate a client and read/write on it(in memory).

Comment: you cannot do file io in blazor WASM. There is an in memory emulated file system but you can only read what you already wrote. You could load the data via an AJAX (AJAJ?) call to the server

Comment: Why?  What are you trying to persist on the client?

Comment: I am not a Blazor developer but I am for PyScript/Pyodide. You can use sqlite in WASM. The sqlite.db database file can be fetched from a web server, stored in browser cache, updated, etc.  https://blog.ouseful.info/2022/02/11/sql-databases-in-the-browser-via-wasm-sqlite-and-duckdb/

Comment: @JohnHanley  Just because you can!  What's the design? Why? What are you trying to achieve?  Are there bettwr ways?

Comment: @pm100 I can totally `<input type="file"/>`  and have the byte array through `MemoryStream` of the db file, so why not? 

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I'm looking to open up files part of an already existing format, not persist per se, but having a way to read it, write into it and re-export it back.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - the browser landscape is trying to evolve into a universal platform. WASM is one of those components. Server-side, browser-side, cloud-edge, etc. The question is if you can, which is yes. I would not necessarily choose that path (WASM) for a database, but AI/ML/Data Science/Data collection applications will be the next killer technology. Databases are just one component. I have written apps that use a database in the browser for offline access (PWA). Then periodically resync with the server. SQLite works well as an in-memory cached database for those types of applications.

Comment: `input type = file` is for uploading a file from the browser hosting OS to the server. That does not sound like what you are asking for

Comment: @JohnHanley.  Forgive my cynicism, but at 66 I seen a few iterations of this before.  A promised utopia of a client that all things to all people, downloads in a jiffy and runs like a F1 car

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - I leave the politics out of my work on Stack Overflow. Can you run SQLite in Wasm? Yes. Is this a panacea? That is for others to decide. Technically, Wasm has a lot of weaknesses that we have seen before in various architectures. Wasm does not even have the concept of a string. You must write lots of bandaid code to make anything serious work. That IMHO was a big mistake in the design. I have extensive language and compiler experience, they should have consulted those who know better while designing the byte code format.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - Never before have we seen a few giant companies absolutely dominate the technology landscape. Google, Microsoft, etc decide what we will be using tomorrow. Take the browser, for example, the developer has ZERO impact on its future. The browser is now so dominant financially that companies must follow whatever Google decides. There are no options in that space. Because of that financial pain point, that technology flows down everywhere. Will Wasm succeed, yes and it does not matter what we think about it.

Comment: @pm100 it's an entrypoint to load the file in memory, it's not meant to be sent

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but not very feasible, as it would lead to some strange behaviors/errors nowadays as you add more data/tables as per my humble experiments.

First, you read the file as a stream via HTTP call and convert it to a base64 string like so:

```
var stream = await Http.GetStreamAsync("sqlite.db"); // file in the wwwroot
var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
using var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
await stream.CopyToAsync(ms);

string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
await JS!.InvokeVoidAsync("fn.writeToCache", base64);
```

Then, this is the *JavaScript* function implementation:

```
window.fn = {
  writeToCache: async function (buffer) {
    const cachePath = `/data/cache/sqlite.db`;
    const cache = await caches.open('your-cache-name');
    const resp = await cache.match(cachePath);

    if (resp && resp.ok) {
      return false;
    } 

    const fileUrl = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + buffer;
    const res = await fetch(fileUrl);
    const blob = await res.blob();

    const headers = new Headers({
      'content-length': blob.size
    });

    const response = new Response(blob, {
      headers
    });

    await cache.put(cachePath, response);

    console.log("Data cached.");

    location.Reload(); // Necessary step to be able to see the cache
  }
}
```

Just a few extra notes:

```
/** Available only in secure contexts. */
declare var caches: CacheStorage; // <-- HTTPS only
declare var crossOriginIsolated: boolean;
declare var crypto: Crypto;
declare var indexedDB: IDBFactory;
// ...
```

- **Secure context**: This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.
- **Headers**: The caching API doesn't honor HTTP caching headers.
- **key Matching** The key matching algorithm depends on the [VARY header](https://www.fastly.com/blog/best-practices-using-vary-header) in the value. So matching a new key requires looking at both key and value for entries in the `Cache` object. For that reason, make sure to version caches by name and use the caches only from the version of the script that they can safely operate on. Here is an example from *Mozilla* on how to get rid from old caches via vanilla *JavaScript*: [Deleting old caches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#deleting_old_caches)